# update storage table from azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I have a function, triggered off a service bus. The bus contains data from several sources, which I want to process and write to a storage table. I can't guarantee there won't be duplicate entries in the bus, but require unique entries in the table. I've figured out I can access an `IAsyncCollector` of my object type, but this doesn't have a way to search for objects that already exist, or to update them. Here's my current function code:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(Run))]
public async Task Run([Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBusTrigger("myBus", Connection = "myCon")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
    [Table("Widgets", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] IAsyncCollector<Widgets> widgetsTable,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"queue trigger function processed message");
            
}
```

How do I access the table in a way that allows me to find/update objects?

Comment: At what price level does the service bus run? Won't the deduplication feature cut it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the output binding for that:

> This output binding **only supports creating new entities** in a table. If you need to update an existing entity from your function code, instead **use an Azure Tables SDK directly.**

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Ctable-api&pivots=programming-language-csharp))

So you need to remove the output binding and leverage the table SDK directly.

Answer (score 0):

I do this using a TableClient and let it deal with duplicates. It will either insert or update a row in a table depending on whether it exists or not.

```
public static async Task<string> TheFunction(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [Table("%TableName%", Connection = "StorageConnectionStringAzure")] TableClient tableClient,
    ILogger log)
{
  ...
  await tableClient.UpsertEntityAsync(theObject, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
  ...
}
```

If you need to know whether what you are updating in the table is the one you want, i.e. perhaps has the latest data for the object, you can use the [TableClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.tables.tableclient?view=azure-dotnet) directly to query the table to see if what's already in there is "out of date" etc.